# Providing Entropy To JVM

Tags: java, random, jvm, bouncycastle

I've been experimenting with the BouncyCastle API for Java and slowly working my way through their "Java Cryptography - Tools and Techniques" ebook. The book contains a short section titled "A Word About Entropy" which states the following:

> What the JVM is using as an entropy source will vary, on Linux for example, it is normally set to “/dev/random” which may block. Usually installing 
>   “rng-tools” or the nearest equivalent will deal with this as it will also 
>   expose any underlying hardware supporting RNG generation to be used for
>   seeding “/dev/random”. With some virtual environments hardware RNG may 
>   never be available, in that case it is important to find other ways of  making entropy available to your JVM. Ways of doing this will vary with the environment you are using.

I might be misunderstanding what this excerpt is saying, but how exactly can I make entropy available to the JVM? The book isn't very specific about this other than stating that the "Ways of doing this will vary with the environment you are using". Is there some kind of Entropy SPI that I am unaware of which can be used to make a source of entropy available to the JVM? My question isn't how to generate entropy or retrieve it from the JVM, but rather, if I already know of and have access to a reliable source of entropy (Such as a file of random bits) how can I make this source of entropy available to the JVM so that it may be used for seeding in cases where other secure sources of entropy are unavailable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may vary depending on the JVM vendor but as per 
[Avoiding JVM Delays Caused by Random Number Generation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss30/configwlss/jvmrand.html) for Sun/Oracle JVM one can set `securerandom.source` property in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` file. This allows to change the source of entropy e.g. from `/dev/random` to `/dev/urandom`.

To add more entropy one can simply write to `/dev/random`. As per [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/9150/180165) this can potentially not be secure but:

> It is also possible to write to /dev/random. This allows any user to mix random data into the pool.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for, the links were very helpful as well. I up voted you as well but unfortunately my votes don't count yet.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your quote is an accurate reflection of at least the Oracle JVM. Here is the Javadoc for the NativePRNG class that is normally chosen by default.

```
public final class NativePRNG extends java.security.SecureRandomSpi
```

> Native PRNG implementation for Solaris/Linux/MacOS. It obtains seed
>   and random numbers by reading system files such as the special device
>   files /dev/random and /dev/urandom. This implementation respects the
>   `securerandom.source` Security property and `java.security.egd` System
>   property for obtaining seed material. If the file specified by the
>   properties does not exist, /dev/random is the default seed source.
>   **/dev/urandom is the default source of random numbers.**
>
> On some Unix platforms, /dev/random may block until enough entropy is
>   available, but that may negatively impact the perceived startup time.
>   By selecting these sources, this implementation tries to strike a
>   balance between performance and security.

As you can see, /dev/urandom and not /dev/random is the default source of entropy.